# Yii - remove smart quotes for all active records

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, smart-quotes

I have an application that allows a user to import/enter information, which gets saved to the MySQL database using a Yii active record, and I have a few users who copy/paste text that has Microsoft smart quotes.  This is an issue when the data is parsed on the iPhone implementation of the site, so I need a way to get rid of all the smart quotes everywhere.

I found a php function that will remove these characters from a piece of text, but I was wondering if there is a way in Yii to have the function get called every time text is saved to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `CActiveRecord` overriding [beforeSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeSave-detail) method in the following manner:

```
class ActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
    protected function removeMagicQuotes($value)
    {
        return your_function_remove_magic_quotes($value);
    }

    protected function beforeSave()
    {
        $attributes = array_keys($this->getAttributes());
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
            $this->$attribute = $this->removeMagicQuotes($this->$attribute);  
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
}
```

This one will remove magic quotes for all attributes declared in active record. As an alternative you can override [beforeValidate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#beforeValidate-detail) method instead of `beforeSave` to remove quotes just before validation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating getter/setter for fields where it can occur and filter it there.

Something like this in case of field `comment`:

```
// Make field $comment private so get/set will work
private $comment = '';
public function getComment()
{
    return clear_function($this->comment);
}

public function setComment($value)
{
    // Could clear here too if you want, so it will be stored clean in db
    $this->comment = $value;
}
```